# possible values for sig in kill function

Tags: c, kill

The man page for the kill function mentions - `int kill(pid_t PID, int sig)` 
It doesn't mention anything about the possible values of the sig argument.
Although I see many sample codes calling it with `SIGKILL`. 
Where did this SIGKILL come from and how to search for it in man pages.
And does this value matters? In the sense I assume no matter what value you specify 
The process with the pid pid_t will indeed get killed

Comment: See also: `man 7 signal` (or read a book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And does this value matters?

Yes, it does. While most signals kill the program, they mean different things and the program can handle them differently. For example, programs can set a SIGSEGV handler then sending a SIGSEGV will no longer kill that program. However, SIGSTOP and SIGKILL (pausing a process and force-killing a process, respectively) are special in that they can't be handled.

You can find a list of signals on [the manpage for signals](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).